# Bootstrap Menu; enable text link while tapping the caret for sub-menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

A menu having a sub-menu cannot link out but just open the sub-menu.
If I remove some attributes, it will not open the sub menu but it can open a link.

Is it possible to have the text link out to href and the caret to open the sub-menu.

[This is an illustration of how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9Nph.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The `dropdown-toggle` has a `href`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="index.html">
    Action
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```